# My lstlisting environment only shows "2" above the first line, instead of numbers before each line, when Hebrew is enabled

Tags: listings, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`backgroundcolor` in `lstset` does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12878/backgroundcolor-in-lstset-does-not-work)

I've recently changed my document skeleton and now my code segments, defined with `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`, changed from looking like this:

```
1 code line
2 code line
3 code line
```

to looking like this:

```
2
  code line
  code line
  code line
```

My listing definition is as follows:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,emph={fence},emphstyle={\underbar},numbers=left,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
```

After pruning my configuration I was able to pinpoint the culprit:

```
\RequirePackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
```

Apparently the lstlisting environment has an issue with Hebrew. How can I solve this?

Comment: We would need more information in order to solve this problem. Something like a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Include your new document class, as well as the versions of files you use (include `\listfiles` in your preamble and extract the contents *after* `*File List*` in your `.log` file).

Comment: @Werner I'll try, but would meanwhile appreciate any general advice about what can even affect lstlisting in the first place

Comment: Your `\lstset` settings seem sufficient to produce the intended output, so there's not much else but an MWE that would help. Bizarre behaviour is sometimes the result of outdated packages (hence my `\listfiles` suggestion). Also include your TeX Distribution (TeX Live, or MiKTeX) and operating system (Windows, Mac, Linux).

Comment: @Werner isolated the culprit and updated my question :)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12878/backgroundcolor-in-lstset-does-not-work